# Extracting even digits from int

Tags: java

Here is the [problem](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building%20Java%20Programs%2C%203rd%20edition%2FBJP3%20Chapter%2012&problem=bjp3-12-e14-evenDigits) that I am solving.

> Write a method evenDigits that accepts an integer parameter n and that
>   returns the integer formed by removing the odd digits from n. The
>   following table shows several calls and their expected return values:

```
Call    Valued Returned
evenDigits(8342116);    8426
evenDigits(4109);   40
evenDigits(8);  8
evenDigits(-34512); -42
evenDigits(-163505);    -60
evenDigits(3052);   2
evenDigits(7010496);    46
evenDigits(35179);  0
evenDigits(5307);   0
evenDigits(7);  0
```

If a negative number with even digits other than 0 is passed to the method, the result should also be negative, as shown above when -34512 is passed.

Leading zeros in the result should be ignored and if there are no even digits other than 0 in the number, the method should return 0, as shown in the last three outputs.

I have this so far -

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    if (n != 0) { 
        int new_x = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        String subS = "";
    String x_str = Integer.toString(n);
        if (x_str.substring(0, 1).equals("-")) {
             temp = Integer.parseInt(x_str.substring(0, 2));
             subS = x_str.substring(2);
        } else {
             temp = Integer.parseInt(x_str.substring(0, 1));
             subS = x_str.substring(1);
        }

        if (subS.length() != 0) {
             new_x = Integer.parseInt(x_str.substring(1));
        }
        
        if (temp % 2 == 0) {
             return Integer.parseInt((Integer.toString(temp) + evenDigits(new_x)));
        } else {
            return evenDigits(new_x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n).chars().filter(x -> x%2 == 0).mapToObj(x -> (char) x)..collect(Collectors.joining()));` or something like that.

Comment: It should be noted that an `int` isn't a decimal number.  The "digits" of the `int`, as represented within the computer, are binary bits.  So returning all "even" digits is a simple matter of returning zero.

Comment: @HotLicks You are conflating the number itself and various ways it can be represented.  The problem statement clearly refers to digits in decimal representation of the number.

Comment: @Misha - Nowhere does the problem mention "decimal", or say that a particular representation should be assumed.  Representation is not mentioned at all.  (*I'm* not the one conflating "number" and "representation".)

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, the problem description is a bit imprecise, but your interpretation calling for the method to always return zero is not consistent with the accompanying examples.  *In light of the examples*, the most reasonable interpretation is that a solution based on radix-10 digits is intended, or at least acceptable.

Comment: These are not examples, they are test cases and are part of the problem statement.  The only radix that allows all test cases to be satisfied is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do people seem always to want to convert to `String` to deal with digits?  Java has perfectly good arithmetic primitives for handling the job.  For example:

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    int rev = 0;
    int digitCount = 0;

    // handle negative arguments
    if (n < 0) return -evenDigits(-n);

    // Extract the even digits to variable rev
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            rev = rev * 10 + n % 10;
            digitCount += 1;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }

    // The digits were extracted in reverse order; reverse them again
    while (digitCount > 0) {
        n = n * 10 + rev % 10;
        rev /= 10;
        digitCount -= 1;
    }

    // The result is in n
    return n;
}
```

Although it makes no difference for a simple academic exercise such as this one, handling the job via arithmetic alone can be expected to perform better than anything involving converting to `String`.

Comment: Why do people always assume that numbers inside a computer are represented in decimal?

Comment: Re: "Why do people seem always to want to convert to string to deal with digits?": In this case, at least, this is clearly a string operation. There is no mathematical relationship between the argument and the result. (Don't get me wrong, I think there's a certain elegance in expressing the string operation using `% 10`, etc.; but an explicit `String` is more natural.)

Comment: Hmm, it almost works. 4109 fails. The answer is coming out as just 4, but it should be 40.

Comment: And it's supposed to be recursively.

Comment: Assigning a new value to the method parameter `n` is non-idiomatic and violates the [principle of least astonisment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Also, as to _why_ people approach problems like this through string tokenization, I think it often makes the code easier to read. Reading code like this takes some time for the not-so-math-inclined.

Comment: @HotLicks internal representation has nothing to do with it.  The problem is about decimal digits.

Comment: Nowhere does the problem say "decimal".

Comment: @Hotlicks, no, it doesn't literally use the word "decimal", but that's far and away the best interpretation in light of the examples (which use all digits 0-9, and no others) and in light of the absence of a radix being explicitly specified.

Comment: @DylanYelton, if you wanted a recursive solution then you should have put that in your question.  Though your starting code is recursive, nothing in the problem description says anything about recursion.

Comment: @DylanYelton, fixed for the case where the last even digit is a zero.

Comment: My point is that the question is bogus.  Without specifying a base one is free to assume any base, and binary is the most reasonable, since that's the form that a "parameter" would be received in.

Answer (score 1):

It's often easier to start with a recursive solution and then work you way back to iterative (if you must):

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return -evenDigits(-n);
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n % 2 == 1) {
        return evenDigits(n / 10);
    } else {
        return 10 * evenDigits(n / 10) + (n % 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Thank you!

Comment: Academic solution to an academic question. Very nice answer! Recursive might not be a good solution, but I wonder if there is possibly any practical application to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 8342116;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Integer.toString(n).chars()
                   .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
                   .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                   .forEachOrdered(sb::append);
int result = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());

System.out.println(result);   // 8426
```

Comment: will fail for any number that consists entirely of odd digits

Comment: This gives the wrong result for negative numbers, and raises an exception for numbers with no even digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int evenDigits(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    boolean neg = false;
    String evenDigits = "";

    if (n < 0) { neg = true; n = abs(n); }

    // keep dividing n until n = 0
    while (n > 0) {
        r = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;         // int division
        if (r % 2 == 0) { evenDigits = Integer.toString(r) + evenDigits; }
    }

    int result = Integer.parseInt(evenDigits);
    if (neg) { result -= 2 * result; }

    return result;
}
```

This is more or less a pseudo code, but I think you get my idea. I have used this method for the same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

A layman's solution that's based on `String`s:

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {

    StringBuilder evenDigitsBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    for (char digitChar : String.valueOf(n).toCharArray()) {
        int digit = Character.getNumericValue(digitChar);
        if (digit % 2 == 0) {
            evenDigitsBuffer.append(digit);
        }
    }

    return evenDigitsBuffer.length() > 0 
            ? Integer.signum(n) * Integer.parseInt(evenDigitsBuffer.toString())
            : 0;
}
```